# Uncaught TypeError: $.get is not a function at <anonymous>:1:3

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I am working on the Google Chrome extension that modifies youtube main page and I am stuck with not being able to execute $.get jQuery function. The jQuery source is included in the json file. The full error message is Uncaught TypeError: $.get is not a function
    at :1:3.

I checked that my jQuery source is not a slim version. My jQuery selectors seem to work well, but when I try to run $.get() it says that it is not a function.

```
//main.js file
//code that works
//removes the content from the page and adds a quote and a picture
let content=$('#contents')
let contentParent = content.parent();
content.remove()
contentParent.prepend("<h1> Get back to achieving your dreams!!!</h1>")
$("h1").addClass("beautText")

//code that doesn`t work
$.get('https://picsum.photos/list', function(result) {
    // result is whatever the URL sends back from the request
    console.log(result)
  })
```

This is my manifest.json file

```
//manifest.json file
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Focus",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description":"This app has a unique functionality that keeps you stayin` focused",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "css": [ "index.css" ],
          "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"],
          "js": ["jquery.min.js","./main.js"]
        }
      ],
    "icons": { 
               "48": "icon48.png"},
    "browser_action": {
               "default_icon": "icon48.png",
              "default_popup": "popup.html",
              "default_title": "Focus!"
            }
  }
```

I expect to get the result [Object,Object,Object...] in the console, but I get an error message that $.get() is not a function. I spent a lot of time to figure out why this happen, but I am really stuck. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: What version of jquery are you using? Can you give us an URL of that version? I'm testing here: https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/vj6wm42z/1/

Comment: Hey!Thanks for your answer. This is a link to the version that I use: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js. I also tried the newest one and it did not work as well.

Comment: This just can't be per the posted code so there's probably something else. Show us the complete extension zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for comments. It seemed to work on other people`s laptops, but not on mine. The answer is simple, but I want to say it in case anyone will also have problems with it: I had hidden console messages in the chrome tools.

I had typed something in the "filter" window and it blocked the messages from popping out in the console.